# Double Integral (Definite)

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

How do you "convert/change" the boundaries for this given integral so that this becomes solvable without involving non-elementary functions? $$\int_{1}^{2}\int_{x}^{x^3}  x^2 e^{y^{2}}\,dydx + \int_{2}^{8}\int_{x}^{8}x^2 e^{y^{2}}\,dydx$$

Comment: Using $TeX$ make your question more readable. Is editing correct?

Comment: It should be $dydx$ not $dxdy$.

Comment: Is your inner integral over $y$?  Usually $dx \ dy$ would indicate that the inner one is over $x$, but having $x$ in the limits seems to indicate that the inner one is $y$.

Comment: Yes, the inner integral is over y. I apologize for my unclear presentation.

Answer (score 1):

**Draw** a picture. The picture should include the curves $y=x^3$ and $y=x$, and should include the territory of both integrals. The key is to identify visually the **combined** regions of integration of our two integrals. See how nicely they fit together.

Together, the two integrals are over the region bounded by the curves $y=x^3$, $y=x$, and $y=8$.

Le's see what happens if we integrate first with respect to $x$.  When we combine the two integrals, we see that $x$ goes from $y^{1/3}$ to $y$.

When we integrate $x^2$, we get $\frac{x^3}{3}$.

Substitute the endpoints. We end up with $\frac{1}{3}(y^3-y)e^{y^2}$.

The integration with respect to $y$ is not difficult. Make the substitution $u=y^2$.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**
Draw the corresponding region of integration and change the order of integration.

Comment: But, when I draw the region of integration for the first term and try to change the order of integration I obtain that x varies from x=y^(1/3) to x=y (when y varies between 1 and 2) and x=y^(1/3) to x=2 (when y varies between 2 and 8) - which does not improve my situation. Again, apologize for my presentation.